# RN v0.14.0-rc running on device, "it looks like the implementation of __DEV__ has changed"

Tags: react-native

In React-Native, I'm trying to load bundle from iphone disk with v0.14.0-rc.

I uncommented this line in **AppDelegate.m**:

`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

then I created the bundle with this command (not sure I need to do it, or is it automatic?):

`react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output main.jsbundle --verbose`

then I'm not sure what to do with the **main.jsbundle** (I added it to the project in xcode). Finally, after installing the app on the iphone, it starts and then hang on white screeen, and here is the error screen from xcode:

[image: screenshot from 2015-11-04 00 01 48]

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **[known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3782)** in the rc and will be fixed in the final release, as this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3646#issuecomment-153108075) confirms.